# Как валидировать пользовательское поле в профиле пользователя в Битриксе?

Tags: битрикс

В профиль пользователя добавил пользовательское поле UF_INN (ИНН), сделал его обязательным. Теперь при сохранении профиля (при пустом поле) ругается. Все замечательно.

Вопрос: как и где можно проверить его на валидность (не js)?

Допустим, метод я напишу, нет проблем, но как его использовать в контексте Битрикс?

Есть предположение, что можно привязаться к событию в init.php и там проверить. Например, есть событие "onAfterResultAdd", однако не пойму, как узнать идентификатор данной формы? И как сделать, чтобы при неуспешной валидации выбрасывалось стандартное сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут 2 варианта действий
1. Вынести компонент профиля пользователя в своей пространство имен и кастомизировать.
2. Использовать `onBeforeResultAdd` и `onBeforeResultUpdate` вместо `onAfterResultAdd` так как вам нужно до сохранения результата проверить поле и отдать ответ пользователю в виде сообщения, в обработчик приходят 3 параметра `WEB_FORM_ID` и поля результатов и их там можно изменить на свои так как они передаются в обработчик по ссылке, просто меняете переменную, почитать про это можно [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/form/events/onbeforeresultupdate.php)